# Derivative problem to minimum building cost

Tags: derivatives

[image]

[image]

Let point S to P is x km.

so cost between P to O should be [(10^2)+x^2]*2

S to P is x*1 million and P to R is (10-x)*1

So total should be [(10^2)+x^2]*2 + x*1 + (10-x)*1 ?

Should I find the stationary points & using second derivative test? :'(

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

the cost function is given by
$K(x)=2Mio\sqrt{10^2+x^2}+1Mio(10-x)$

Answer (score 0):

i got $x=\frac{10}{\sqrt{3}}$ and the minimal costs are $10(1+\sqrt{3})$

Comment: The result for the minimal costs have to be multiplied by 1,000,000.